# Correct Interface for non-blocking slow sampling sensor driver

Tags: c, linux, kernel, device-driver

I am writing a device driver for an i2c connected temperature/pressure gauge.

To operate the sensor, once first requests a new reading. The sensor will then perform the necessary sampling over a period of time and then report back the final readings. This process is expected to take some time.

Userspace is expected to connect to the device driver using the Character Device interface using file based `read`s and possibly `ioctl`s.

I can easily create a blocking interface where the user thread attempts a read and remains blocked until I am able to report back the sensor reading.

I would like to allow the driver to work in non-blocking mode since sampling is expected to take some time. The user thread can the either do other stuff or block on poll/select until the sampling is complete.

The problem is that I need the `read` to instruct the driver to start sampling but the driver cannot complete the `read` until the sampling is completed and in non-blocking mode, the driver is not allowed to block the thread between these two states.

As an added consideration, I would like to minimize the number of kernel calls invoked to perform this operation. I also need to ensure that precious power is not wasted on unnecessary sampling.

What is the correct Linux pattern for doing this?

Update: I am not interested in the implementation details, what I am really after is the design of the user/kernel interface that follows good practice.

Comment: Have you checked out the example character driver in [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), [chapter 6 (PDF)](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch06.pdf) in particular? I personally would suggest that a `read()` or `lseek()` attempt would initiate data gathering, with normal `read()` blocking for the duration. (It may be that the calling process has nothing else to do, so this would be natural.) For `O_NONBLOCK`, the initial read will return `-EWOULDBLOCK` until data is available; but also support `SIGIO` and polling. The LDD3 book does describe all these in detail.

Comment: Which hygrometer sensor? Can you post your full code somewhere (github etc)? I've been writing a lot of this type of code lately and am curious.

Answer (score 0):

Do the necessary sampling on sensor use work queue or other asynchronous primitive in the open method. In the work function, use wait_queue to notify poll the device is readable.

in the open method:

```
work_function()
{
    /*perform the necessary sampling*/
    /*after done, use wait queue to notify poll the device is readable.*/
}
DECLARE_WORK(name, work_function, data);

static int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    /*do other stuff....*/
    queue_work(.......);   
}

static unsigned int scull_p_poll(struct file *filp, poll_table *wait)
{
    poll_wait(filp, &dev->outq, wait);
    .......
    return mask;
}
```

LDD chapter 7 will helpful.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I start the measurement on the open. If there is a long wait after the open before the read, I might be getting stale data.

Comment: Actually, poll also make the process wait, it just can monitor multiple fd,how about start the measurement in the poll?  SIGIO maybe a better solution @doron

Comment: Starting the process in the poll has merit, the only outstanding issue is what to do about stale data.